# UserForm Label External Font (woff2 file)

Tags: vba, excel

I want to change the font of my label to a custom one that I got (Font.woff2) but I can't figure out how to do it.

Something like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Label1.Font.Name = "path"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. WOFF2 is a web font format and and cannot be used in Windows or Excel only in websites.
2. A font can only be used if it is installed in Windows and not by its path.

So the only thing you can do is install a Windows compatible font in Windows and then use it by its name. WOFF2 will not work.

Comment: Okay thanks. I converted it to ttf, installed and it kind of worked (it's a bit different probably from the convertion).